# Hash detection and page processing

Tags: hash, tabs, hyperlink

I have page with jquery tabs. Every tab has it's own link (mysite.com/index.html#tab1). There is also my js function which works when clicking on the tab links - it changes some content on the page depending on the tab which was clicked. 
**THE QUESTION:**
I need to enable my js function when visitor comes on the site by the link with specific hash, but not just by clicking on the tab. It means that I need to detect which # is in the URL and perform the specific function for specific # in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript and check if the url contains any `#` and get what the `#` is, and then alter the page appropriately.

```
// get the current url.
var URL = window.location;
// URL = 'http://example.net/#displayme'; // just an example that will work.
var hashtag = 'null';

try{
    // get a substring of everything after the # excluding the '#'
    hashtag = URL.substr(URL.indexOf('#') + 1, URL.length); 

    if(hashtag == 'someVar'){
         // change content
    }
} catch(err){
    //the url didn't contain a #
}

document.write(hashtag);
```

The above script basically checks the URL and tries to find if it contains any #, You could place the script in the `$(document).ready(function() { addScriptHere(); });` function so that it's called once the page has loaded, and use jQuery to alter the page in whichever way you desire.

Output in the above example using the commented out URL

> displayme